# Any recommendation on how to manage ads?

Tags: plugins, multisite, ads, adsense

I am in the process of creating a network of >40 sites with wordpress, and I am trying to put together the base that each site will use, for example all the sites will use google analytics so I will use this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/ plugin for that. For sitemaps I will use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bwp-google-xml-sitemaps/, etc. (These plugins works well with wp multisite)

All the sites will use google adsense, so I was wondering if someone knows some plugin or something that will help managing the ads directly from the dashboard, taking in count this will be a multisite environment.

I browsed the wp plugins directory but I didn't find anything good, I'd like to hear if someone is already using something for managing ads and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [AdRotate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adrotate/), it's quite good. You can define block of ads that are displayed randomly (at will) at each page load. You can define single ads and the put it in your theme.

You can paste the adsense code in the blocks, and you can manage all the aspects from the backend.

Give it a try.

Comment: I decided to simply use shortcodes, I will look if I can find some plugin or maybe ill code it myself, thanks.